# Debug possible escaped-text issue in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I have an XSL template that gives different results when used in two different contexts.

The template manifesting the defect is:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="blah">
    <!-- snip irrelevant stuff -->
    <xsl:if test="see">
       <xsl:message>Contains a cross-ref. <xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Given:

```
<el>This is a '<see cref="foo"/>' cross-referenced element.</el>
```

In one situation, I get the desired result:

```
Contains a cross-ref. This is a ' ' cross-referenced element.
```

(the `<see/>` is being dealt with as an XML element and is ultimately matched by another template.)

But in another situation, the `xsl:if` doesn't trigger and if I output the contents with `<xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="."/>`, I get:

```
This is a '<see cref="foo"/>' cross-referenced element.
```

It seems to me that in the latter improperly-behaving scenario, it's acting like it's been output-escaped. Does that make sense? Am I barking up the wrong tree? This is a typically complex XSL situation and trying to trace the call-stack is difficult; is there a particular XSLT processing command I should be looking for?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at your input.  It sounds like the `<see>` elements are sometimes XML-escaped and sometimes not escaped.

Comment: Yes, I agree that is how it appears. Both paths are based on the same input data, though, so the escaping must somehow be done by XSLT. I am asking for advice on how to discover where that is done (as the overall processing is quite complex: just grepping for "disable-output-escaping='yes'" has not made anything obvious).